# Making a plane seat chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use a plane seat map generator. What it does is really simple. You insert the passengers for first, business and economy on html inputs. And automatically a chart should appear. This work is perform by javascript. I'm trying to run it but something is going wrong. It just does not work. It shows the table where you should put the inputs and a number 7 under it. I guess that's happening because I am missing some javascript. When you fill the input nothing happens.

To make it easier I put the code on jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/g4kzo4fo/

Because I have to paste code here you have my javascript. I think the problem is somewhere here:

```
makeRequest(request, id, false);

    $('#'+id).dialog({ width: 'auto', height: 'auto', modal: true, resizable: false });
    $('#'+id).dialog('open');
}

var AircraftConfigCheck = {
    capacity :  200,
    business :  0,
    economy:    0,
    first:      0,
    businessFree : 0,
    economyFree : 0,
    firstFree: 0,

    total : function() {
        return (parseInt(this.business) || 0) * 2 + (parseInt(this.economy) || 0) + (parseInt(this.first) || 0) * 4;
    },

    checkBusiness : function() {
        if( this.total() > this.capacity ) {
            this.business = Math.floor( ( this.capacity - this.economy - this.first * 4 ) / 2 );
        }
    },

    checkEconomy : function() {
        if( this.total() > this.capacity ) {
            this.economy = this.capacity - this.business * 2 - this.first * 4;
        }
    },

    checkFirst : function() {
        if( this.total() > this.capacity ) {
            this.first = Math.floor( ( this.capacity - this.economy - this.business * 2 ) / 4 );
        }
    },

    updateCapacity : function() {
        this.businessFree = Math.max( 0, Math.floor( ( this.capacity - this.total() ) / 2 ) );
        this.firstFree = Math.max( 0, Math.floor( ( this.capacity - this.total() ) / 4 ) );
        this.economyFree = Math.max( 0, this.capacity - this.total() );
    },

    setValues : function() {
        $("#business").val( this.business ); 
        $("#economy").val( this.economy ); 
        $("#first").val( this.first ); 
        $("#businessFree").html( this.businessFree ); 
        $("#economyFree").html( this.economyFree ); 
        $("#firstFree").html( this.firstFree ); 
        /*$("#first").val( this.total() ); */
        this.render();
    },

    render : function() {
        makeRequest('http://www.fsairlines.net/crewcenter/aircraft_config_ajax.php5?max_pax='+this.capacity+
            '&first_seats='+this.first+
            '&business_seats='+this.business+
            '&economy_seats='+this.economy,
            'aircraft',
            true
        );
    }
 }

$(function() {
    $(".seatInput").keyup(function() {
        switch( $(this).attr("id") ) {
            case "economy": 
                AircraftConfigCheck.economy = $("#economy").val();
                AircraftConfigCheck.checkEconomy();
                AircraftConfigCheck.updateCapacity();
                AircraftConfigCheck.setValues();
                break;

            case "business":
                AircraftConfigCheck.business = $("#business").val();
                AircraftConfigCheck.checkBusiness();
                AircraftConfigCheck.updateCapacity();
                AircraftConfigCheck.setValues();
                break;

            case "first":
                AircraftConfigCheck.first = $("#first").val();
                AircraftConfigCheck.checkFirst();
                AircraftConfigCheck.updateCapacity();
                AircraftConfigCheck.setValues();
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

**LASTEST UPDATE:** http://jsfiddle.net/g4kzo4fo/4/

Comment: <div class="placeholder">7</div>

Comment: @vals What do you mean with that? This is the result of the request on the javascript.

Comment: the number 7 is in your html, where I said

Answer (score 2):

You have quite a few syntax errors in your code which is why it isn't running.

This part of the code doesn't make any sense:

```
makeRequest(request, id, false);

    $('#'+id).dialog({ width: 'auto', height: 'auto', modal: true, resizable: false });
    $('#'+id).dialog('open');
}
```

The `makeRequest()` function doesn't exist so you can't call it.  And, there's an extraneous `}` at the end of this block.

Then, later inside the render function, you try to call `makeRequest()` again, but it doesn't exist.

---

The very first thing you should do when running any Javascript code that you've just written is to check the error console or debug console in the browser for errors.  Then, anytime that something isn't working properly check the console again.  Then, when you're testing your code, check the error console again.

Comment: Watch the new code http://jsfiddle.net/g4kzo4fo/2/ Still not working there are more problems

Comment: @carlosremove - Please take my suggestion and look in the browser error console and see the errors that it reports there and then fix those errors.  Your latest code still shows errors.  We are here to help teach you how to fix your own code.

Comment: Well, right now it is showing  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`. But why? I got stuck here http://jsfiddle.net/g4kzo4fo/4/

Comment: @carlosremove - because `mainText` is `null`.  It is `null` because there is no object in your HTML that has an `id="container"`.